# The output result does not change when Enter different input in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I Built the model  with my data set and 
my website idea is the user Enter Numbers 
the user inputs I will input it to my model to predict the result as a percentage  based on the user Entered

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # submit action button
observeEvent(input$submit, {
    model_NaiveBayes <- naiveBayes(outcome~., data=BC_bind21,probability=TRUE)#use naiveBayes
    dfInput21  <- data.frame(input$F1,input$F2,input$F3)
     predict_Models<- reactive({
     predict(model_NaiveBayes,newdata = dfInput21, type= "raw")[,1]
       })
       #show the result 
 output$result <- renderText({
 predict_Models()
 })
  }
```

but the Result from first input does not change when I Enter other values

How can Update the result, or connect the result with inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is syntactically wrong and missing things for test, but here's a thought.

You are mistaking how *reactivity* works: you are making reactive something that does not need it, and missing those that do.

- `model_NaiveBayes` is unchanged by inputs, actions, or events, so it does not need to be reactive (you can make it so, but it's unnecessarily adding complexity to your app)
- `dfInput21` depends on user inputs, so needs to be reactive
- `predict_NaiveBayes` is dependent on the data from `dfInput21` (which is reactive), so needs to be reactive

Another issue: assigning value to a variable within a block (e.g., `reactive`, `observe`, `observeEvent`) does not make that variable available outside of that block. Think about it: you are saying that that variable (to which you just assigned) will change based on something else that happens. That is the definition of *reactivity*, so needs to be handled as such.

Also, I don't know how you are setting up the UI, but if `predict_Models()` fires before `input$F1` (...) is properly set, you'll see transient failures. For this, I recommend the use of `req` to say effectively *"I need `dfInput21()` to be 'truthy' before you evaluate the rest of a block"*. ("Truthy" is based on things like not `NULL`. See `?isTruthy` and the source `shiny::isTruthy` for more.) There are many other things `req` can be used for, not just variable "goodness", but also validation. For instance, `req(input$F1 > 0)` works as one might expect. If the `req` expression fails, the rest of the block is not executed (and the downstream UI elements are not adversely affected).

Finally, I find keeping data as its own reactive "thing" typically makes sense. If any other table/plot/block needs the data, then keeping the data by itself makes a lot of sense. Keeping it separate even if there's only one consumer adds very little complexity to the shiny internal-dependency table, but it is also quite expressive in that *"this variable is always 'raw' data"*. (Related is that it might be useful to not immediately filter results from `predict`, so I moved the `[,1]` from the call to `predict` to the presentation of it.

So a direct translation of your app could look like:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  model_NaiveBayes <- naiveBayes(outcome~., data=BC_bind21,probability=TRUE)#use naiveBayes
  # submit action button
  dfInput21 <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    req(input$F1,input$F2,input$F3)
    data.frame(input$F1,input$F2,input$F3)
  })
  predict_Models <- reactive({
    req(dfInput21())
    predict(model_NaiveBayes, newdata = dfInput21(), type= "raw")
  })
  #show the result 
  output$result <- renderText({
    req(predict_Models())
    predict_Models()[,1]
  })
}
```

If you wanted to reduce things a little, you could combine `dfInput21` and `predict_Models`, though you lose access to the "user-defined input data" as raw data (probably not a factor here).

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  model_NaiveBayes <- naiveBayes(outcome~., data=BC_bind21,probability=TRUE)#use naiveBayes
  # submit action button
  predict_Models <- reactive({
    req(input$F1,input$F2,input$F3)
    dfInput21 <- data.frame(input$F1,input$F2,input$F3) # not available outside this block
    predict(model_NaiveBayes, newdata = dfInput21, type= "raw")
  })
  #show the result 
  output$result <- renderText({
    req(predict_Models())
    predict_Models()[,1]
  })
}
```

Comment: Reem, I re-edited the code. I don't really know if this works; if things aren't working for you then you need to update your question with sample data and the remainder of your code. (If it does work ... feel free to ["accept" this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).)

Comment: I get Error ` Error in predict: object 'model_NaiveBayes' not found` because must be all in parentheses of 
`eventReactive(input$submit, { })` , right?

Comment: thank you for the explanation.
I tried to use the first code, but I get the same problem
the result is same does not change.

when I tried to use the second code
I don't get any result!

Comment: I normally try to provide *tested* code when I answer, but without complete code and sample data, that's it. These are some references for improving question quality, including making it *reproducible*: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Did you figure it out, Reem?